# How to identify the culprit in a printing problem

Tags: xubuntu, printing

I need a way to identify the culprit in this problem, so I know where the error is happening.

I have a Perl script I've used forerver that front-ends enscript(1) to pretty-print text files for me.  I'm on Xubuntu 16.04.5, with enscript version 1.6.5.90-2, which synaptic says is the latest one.

Suddenly I've noticed that it's printing about 3/4 inch too low on the page and is dropping some lines off the lower edge of the page.  Everything else seems normal.

Now recently there have been software updates of course, but I don't if any touched enscript.  And I don't know how to find out.

I have also had to swap out the printer.  It was HP and now I have a Brother.  That would normally make me suspect the printer, but LibreOffice and evince are printing normally on that printer.  Then again enscript uses Postscript and I don't know what LibreOffice or evince use.

I've captured the evince command that runs my test sample by adding debugging lines to the Perl front-end.  It reads

```
enscript -MLetter    --indent=3 --tabsize=8 --fancy-header=print --header=" . . . HELEN/history.txt" -t title sustaining-20180828-history.txt
```

I eliminated --fancy-header as the problem (problem persists when I let enscript use the default header style) and none of the other options seem suspicious.  I've captured the Postscript too, but it's 800 lines and hard to read.  I used to work with Postscript directly but it's been a couple of decades at least.

I don't know what tool(s) to try next.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that your code is generating in a font that was not stored on either or both of the printers. If a font is not stored and not supplied in the print job, the printer will select what it thinks is a good equivalent. Of course this is prone to issues. In this case line height may be different and one or more characters are not being recognised. Something like that anyway.

Cheers Paul

Comment: A reasonable concern, but every character I would expect actually appears in the output.  Just in the wrong place.